# PowerMockito .when().thenReturn() with randomUUID not returning expected value

Tags: java, spring, junit, uuid, powermockito

I'm trying to test a Web Service method which connects to a SQL Server Database which contains JCR nodes, as we're using JackRabbit.

The method looks like:

```
public String addDocumentByJson(String fileName, byte[] fileContent, int status, String userName, String jsonProperties) {
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    // It does a bunch of operations here
    return jsonResult;
}
```

Where `jsonResult` is an object similar to this one:

```
{
    "id" : "<A random UUID>"
    "version" : 1
}
```

Now, when I try to test it following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36331711/2180785) and the code in [this post](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/11/29/using-another-junit-runner-with-powermock/) and I came off with the following code (which as I said is based on the past links):

```
@PrepareForTest({ UUID.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/TestSpringConfig.xml")
public class TestJackRabbitService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jackRabbitService")
    IJackRabbitService jackRabbitService;

    private byte[] fileContent;
    private int versionFile;

    public TestJackRabbitService() {
        classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        LOG.trace("Run @BeforeClass");
        try {
            fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("fileTest.txt"))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        LOG.trace("Run @Before");
        try {
            versionFile = jackRabbitService.getLastVersionOf(nameApp, nameFile); //This method returns an int,
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddDocumentsByJson() {
        //Some tests which run correctly

        final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        mockStatic(UUID.class);
        LOG.debug(uuid);
        //doReturn(uuid).when(UUID.randomUUID());
        when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);
        idFile = uuid;

        assertEquals(jackRabbitService.addDocumentByJson(nameFile, bytes, nameApp, 5, jsonproperties), "{\"id\":\"" + uuid + "\",\"version\":1}");
    }
}
```

However when I test this method it gives me the following results:

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
    testAddDocumentsByJson(com.optimissa.test.junit.TestJackRabbitService): expected:<{"id":"[1efaf3b8-ca7c-4e6f-878f-102d9a7a92d9]","version":1}> but was:<{"id":"[cfa1a8b0-be6a-46b1-90f5-d2f6d230796a]","version":1}>
```

As you can see both UUIDs are different, and from what I read on my first link in this question is that it should return the same UUID everytime the static method `UUID.randomUUID()` is called (the one stored in the `uuid` variable inside the `TestJackRabbitService` class...

I also tried with `doReturn` method as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38681915/2180785) but it produces the following stack trace:

```
testAddDocumentsByJson(com.optimissa.test.junit.TestJackRabbitService)  Time elapsed: 5.279 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.optimissa.test.junit.TestJackRabbitService.testAddDocumentsByJson(TestJackRabbitService.java:143)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:182)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:164)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:134)
    at com.optimissa.test.junit.TestJackRabbitService.testAddDocumentsByJson(TestJackRabbitService.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:149)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417676/2180785) I read (but I don't understand) that maybe I need to create a new object from the class I'm trying to test? I'm injecting the dependency at the very beginning of the test class, I'm really new to `JUnit` testing and english is not my native language, however I can comprehend most of thing but that answer is giving me a hard time understanding it (due to my lack of knowledge in JUnit testing).

How can I make my `JUnit` test to retrieve the same ID which is generated inside the method (or intercept the call to `UUID.randomUUD()` to return the value inside my `JUnit` test) ?

---

### Edit

After trying @hammerfest's answer, with the following changes:

```
UUID uuid = PowerMockito.mock(UUID.class);

mockStatic(UUID.class);
when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);

String jsonToCompare = "{\"id\":\"" + uuid + "\",\"version\":1}";
String jsonFromJRS = jackRabbitService.addDocumentByJson(nameFile, bytes, nameApp, 5, jsonproperties);

assertEquals(jsonFromJRS, jsonToCompare);
```

I still get this result:

```
testAddDocumentsByJson(com.optimissa.test.junit.TestJackRabbitService): expected:<{"id":"[493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f]","version":1}> but was:<{"id":"[00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]","version":1}>
```

Comment: @JarrodRoberson this isn't a dup, since the question linked is asking *"How to Unit test using an UUID"* in my case, I clearly stated that I tried with the accepted answer of such question which gave me a failed test, I'm asking for a particular question not a generic one in this case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Common mistake with mocking system classes it's that they are added to `@PrepareForTest`, but unfortunately it's impossible to mock final Java System classes directly. But PowerMock provides [workaround](https://blog.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/). PowerMock replaces calls to system classes by call to PowerMock class. A class that use final system class should be added to `@PrepareForTest`

I've added [example](https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/blob/master/system-classes/src/test/java/example/powermock/systemclasess/service/DocumentServiceTest.java) how to mock UUID.

```
public class DocumentService {

  public JsonDocument saveDocument(JsonDocument document){
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    document.setId(uuid.toString());
    return document;
  }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DocumentService.class)
public class DocumentServiceTest {
@Test
public void should_set_id() throws Exception {
    final String id = "493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f";
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id);

    mockStatic(UUID.class);
    when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);

    DocumentService documentService = new DocumentService();

    JsonDocument document = new JsonDocument();
    documentService.saveDocument(document);

    assertThat(document.getId())
        .as("Id is set")
        .isEqualTo(id);
  }
}
```

You may find more in [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System).

Comment: This one seems to work, and as you are a PowerMock contributor, I assume this is the expected resolution. What I don't understand is that the 2009 article you linked is apparently from the same author, who then declared "not possible to solve" and suggested the all 0s workaround in the 2015 github ticket I linked. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The ticket that you linked was imported in the 2015 from Google Source to GitHub. But anyway, it was created and answered later then the post. I think, that it was missunderstanding. As you may see from example it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I've reused and modified @hammerfest s example a bit which work on my machine.

The first case simply mocks the static invocation of the UUID class and asserts that the returned UUID of the SUT equals the mocked UUID:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.util.UUID;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@PrepareForTest({ UUID.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class StaticMockTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MyClass sut = new MyClass();

    UUID uuidLocal = UUID.randomUUID();
    mockStatic(UUID.class);
    when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuidLocal);

    assertThat(sut.getUUID(), is(equalTo(uuidLocal)));
  }

  private class MyClass {

    public UUID getUUID() {
      return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
  }
}
```

The second case invokes a method of a Spring managed bean which returns the mocked UUID:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@PrepareForTest({ UUID.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(DefaultTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {StaticMockTest2.ContextConfig.class},
    loader= AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*"})
public class StaticMockTest2 {

  @Resource
  private MyClass sut;

  @Test
  public void test() {

    UUID uuidLocal = UUID.randomUUID();
    mockStatic(UUID.class);
    when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuidLocal);

    assertThat(sut.getUUID(), is(equalTo(uuidLocal)));
  }

  private static class MyClass {

    public UUID getUUID() {
      return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
  }

  @Configuration
  public static class ContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass() {
      return new MyClass();
    }
  }
}
```

Both tests work on my machine though I'd suggest to refactor the UUID generation into a utility class which you instantiate and inject via Spring. Then you can simply replace the PowerMock stuff with ordinary Mockito mocking and avoid dealing with such problems:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockTest3.ContextConfig.class},
    loader= AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MockTest3 {

  @Resource
  private Util mockUtil;
  @Resource
  private MyClass sut;

  @Test
  public void test() {

    UUID uuidLocal = UUID.randomUUID();
    when(mockUtil.generateUUID()).thenReturn(uuidLocal);

    assertThat(sut.getUUID(), is(equalTo(uuidLocal)));
  }

  private static class MyClass {

    private Util util;

    public MyClass(Util util) {
      this.util = util;
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
      return util.generateUUID();
    }
  }

  private static class Util {

    public UUID generateUUID() {
      return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
  }

  @Configuration
  public static class ContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public Util mockUtil() {
      return mock(Util.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass() {
      return new MyClass(mockUtil());
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to rely on Spring for testing (to speed up things even further) you can inject the dependencies yourself either via constructor injection or via `Whitebox.setInternalState(sut, "fieldName", mockObject);` or Springs `ReflectionUtils.setField(sut, "fieldName", mockObject);`.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

public class MockTest4 {

  @Test
  public void test() {

    Util mockUtil = mock(Util.class);
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(mockUtil);

//    MyClass sut = new MyClass();
//    Whitebox.setInternalState(sut, "util", mockUtil);

    UUID uuidLocal = UUID.randomUUID();
    when(mockUtil.generateUUID()).thenReturn(uuidLocal);

    assertThat(sut.getUUID(), is(equalTo(uuidLocal)));
  }

  private class MyClass {

    @Resource
    private Util util;

    public MyClass() {}
    public MyClass(Util util) {
      this.util = util;
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
      return util.generateUUID();
    }
  }

  private class Util {

    public UUID generateUUID() {
      return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
  }
}
```

The last test contains both options, constructor or field injection, you can play with.

---

Due to @hammerfest s comment I'm adding a further example here that showcases what to do if `MyClass` is externally defined. Note this example was basically taken from [Github](https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/blob/master/system-classes/src/test/java/example/powermock/systemclasess/service/DocumentServiceTest.java) before I read the answer of @ArthurZagretdinov, who is probably the author of this test in first place (as pointed out by @hammerfest in the comments). First the standalone `MyClass` implementation:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class MyClass {

  public UUID getUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID();
  }
}
```

Next, the test that uses the external `MyClass` definition:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.util.UUID;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@PrepareForTest({ MyClass.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class StaticMockTest3 {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MyClass sut = new MyClass();

    final String id = "493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f";
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id);

    // UUID uuidLocal = UUID.randomUUID();
    mockStatic(UUID.class);
    when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuidLocal);
    // when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuidLocal);

    assertThat(sut.getUUID().toString(), is(equalTo(uuid.toString())));
  }
}
```

If you comment out both comment-lines in the above cenario, you will figure out that the test will fail due to unequal UUIDs. This means that the preparation for `MyClass` does also respect using the declared UUID mock and thus can be used for mocking static classes.

Comment: The essential difference compared to my example seems to be that you have made MyClass an inner class of the test itself. This indeed seems to work, but I doubt OP can do the same in his real life environment.

Comment: @hammerfest Instead of preparing UUID for testing you should prepare MyClass for testing in that particular case. Furthermore, my answer also contains approaches on how to avoid PowerMock or even Spring completly, which is preferable for testing IMO

Comment: Well IMHO it is not a "particular" case, it is "the" case, while assuming SUT to be an inner class of the test is basically changing the environment you are testing; but let's see whether it is acceptable for OP. Btw. excellent job of copying the essence of Arthur Zagretdinov's answer (even the UUID value is the same) without giving any credit to him.

Comment: @hammerfest I took (probably his) example from the github which is accessible via the link you've postet, as I didn't read his SO answer here before I updated my post. I admit that I copied the source and modified it slightly, my bad for not linking to the github example. The essence of my post though is that there are multiple ways to test with UUIDs (and I prefere avoiding PowerMock when possible).

Comment: BTW, @RomanVottner , if extract generation UUID to separate class and provide interface then there's no reason to use Spring or the WhiteBox class. Mockito has `InjectMocks`, EasyMock had `TestSubject` for these purpose.

Comment: @ArthurZagretdinov I agree that this is not necessary, this is just a personal taste. Certain definitions could also be refactored to a `@Before` annotated method and such like. Though, for the sake of readability I tend to keep everything test-related in the method itself. I prefere constructor-injection over field injection as it is more natural to state that certain dependencies are necessary. Though, plenty of people still use field-injection and the way presented in the code just explicitely states that this dependency needs to be present in the SUT.